# How can I implement the search for square numbers whose difference are again squares using the GIMPS platform?

Tags: c++, primes, distributed-computing

I would like to search for quadruples `[w,x,y,z]` where the difference of their squares are all again a square: `z^2-y^2`, `z^2-x^2`, `z^2-w^2`, `y^2-x^2`, `y^2-w^2` and `x^2-w^2` are all square numbers.

For this I would like to use the [GIMPS (Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search)](https://www.mersenne.org/) plattform for a distributed search.

I would be very grateful for a jump start or solution on how I can implement such an application.

**What we have so far:** We have already a solution based on `C++` that searches for such quadruples (see this [GitHub Link](https://github.com/Sultanow/pythagorean/blob/main/cpp/prog_ssd_optimized.cpp)). And it searched already up to `2^34`. However, a distributed search seems to be much more promising in terms of scalability.

Comment: Although GIMPS itself searches only for Mersenne Prime Numbers, but on their [forum](https://www.mersenneforum.org/) they discuss a lot of other unrelated questions, including many other mathematical tasks, and often interested people create from scratch useful code snippets to solve these off-topic tasks. So quite probable that GIMPS people can be intersted in solving your very challenging task, if not using GIMPS platform itself then at least maybe using GIMPS C/C++ library code. But GIMPS itself often extends their GUI soft more and more, so might be interested in our task too.